# $DistributedContexts and ParallelEvaluate

Tags: parallelization

This is a small question regarding the relationship between the [`$DistributedContexts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DistributedContexts.html) variable and the [`ParallelEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) command. Specifically, the Properties and Relations section of the documentation of the former documents the following behaviour:

> Find all parallel functions that currently use `$DistributedContexts`:
>
> ```
>  Select[Names["System`Parallel*"], 
>   MemberQ[Options[Symbol[#]], 
>     DistributedContexts :> $DistributedContexts] &]
> ```
>
> [image]

However, if I evaluate that code I get

```
{"ParallelArray","ParallelCombine","ParallelDo","ParallelEvaluate", "ParallelMap",
"ParallelProduct", "ParallelSum", "ParallelTable", "ParallelTry"}
```

which differs from the above by the addition of `ParallelEvaluate`. I find this pretty bizarre, as that function is present since v7.0, and it is quite natural for it to have

```
Options[ParallelEvaluate]

(* -> {DistributedContexts :> $DistributedContexts}*)
```

Is this behaviour version-dependent? Can someone explain why that function is missing from that list? Or is this simply a documentation bug?

---

**Update**: I have been in touch with WRI and they concur that this is a documentation bug, so it should probably be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is version-dependent and this is currently a documentation bug.

`ParallelEvaluate` acquired the `DistributedContexts` option as of version 10.4.0. The documentation example should have been reevaluated to reflect the new behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll report it in the morning.

Comment: Just to confirm, though, you're saying ParallelEvaluate did not have this option in v10.3?

Comment: Correct, it was only introduced in 10.4.